# how to split content from RichTextField into 2 columns in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a model where I am using `RichTextField` (CKEditor) and I'd like to know if there is any way to spit the content in the HTML file into 2 columns in the same way you do it with columns in the Bootstrap grid system.

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    ...
    test_content = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

test.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="border bg-grey text-white rounded">
        <h2 class="fw-bold text-uppercase">Test header</h2>
        <div>{{test.test_content|safe}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content now is displayed in 1 column and it is not a list so I cannot implement col-6 or something similar because it is not a loop. Any ideas or tips on how can this be implemented?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is with CSS, rather than at the template level: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for